# How to bind SD card to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there a way to make sure that SD card of Raspberry PI works only with particular  device only?

I do not want anyone to use the SD card with any other Raspberry Pi device other than specified.

Is there a way out?

Comment: what is your end goal/what are you trying to protect ? How about simply changing the default username and password (using raspi-config) and setting it up so it doesn't boot into automatically into the desktop session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way do do this. Of course you can build some trickeries based on Device Informations (fsys and udev) and crypt your disk. But, it is clearly impossible to guarantee system integrity when the storage device is physically reachable: anyone can mount it and some aware/clever guy, using enough time and effort, shall reverse engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

See this guide for Arch linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_Encryption
If you encrypt your filesystem only he have the password can decrypt the sdcard. This prevent unauthorize access for example from the Windows/Linux to the sd card files.

But if you boot from the PC you are in the same problem.
The only thing that comes to mind is to make a script that controls a device that exists only on raspberry is available and if not, automatically encrypt the system.